# Why such a difference between memory_usage() and memory_usage(deep=True)?

Tags: python, pandas

Could someone detail what the parameter deep=True does when calling a DataFrame's memory_usage method? I understand from the doc that it "drills" into the columns that have the object dtype, to see how much the values actually take in memory. But what is the "right" value then? How much of my memory does the DataFrame actually take?

I loaded a file that is about 2GB on disk in DataFrame `df`. Without deep I have the feeling I have the right value, because I get something close to the size of the file. With `deep=true`... I get 7 times this value, and my PC doesn't even have enough RAM to contain this!

```
>>> memus = df.memory_usage()
>>> memusdeep = df.memory_usage(deep=True)
>>> print(memus.sum() / 10**9, 'GB')
1.874067408 GB
>>> print(memusdeep.sum() / 10**9, 'GB') # that's very much!
13.897614776 GB
```

If I look at the memory used by the python program in task manager, I see a value varying from 250MB to about 1.87GB (the same as `deep=False`). Does this mean that my columns are "released" from memory when not used, and that if I use all of them the total memory usage could reach the 13.9 GB announced by `deep=True`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This difference is due to any columns that contain strings or objects. Strings are treated as an object by Pandas, and `df.memory_usage()` does not consider the size of objects by default when `deep=False`. You must specify `deep=True` to get a more accurate measurement of the size of any DataFrame that contains strings or objects.

My DataFrame has 560,897 rows and 1 column with 38 character strings in every row. `df.memory_usage()` returns 4,487,176 bytes for this column, which is 8 bytes per string. However, a 38 character string cannot be stored in only 8 bytes. `df.memory_usage(deep=True)` returns 53,285,215 bytes. This is 95 bytes per string, which is only slightly more than the size of a single built-in string variable in Python.

A column in the same dataframe with `dtype=int32` returns 2,243,588 bytes regardless of whether `deep = True`, and also regardless of the value of each integer.

There is also very good explanation here:
https://pythonspeed.com/articles/pandas-dataframe-series-memory-usage/

Answer (score 1):

How I understand it, first the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.memory_usage.html).

It talks about **bytes**, and you need to understand what a **byte** is. I link to you the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte). Now, we're going to take the example of the documentation and understand it. You need to understand a *little bit* of how types work in a lower level language, such as C or C++ (for instance, *int*, *float*, ...).

```
dtypes = ['int64', 'float64', 'complex128', 'object', 'bool']
data = dict([(t, np.ones(shape=5000).astype(t))
             for t in dtypes])
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.head()
#   int64  float64  complex128 object  bool
#0      1      1.0      (1+0j)      1  True
#1      1      1.0      (1+0j)      1  True
#2      1      1.0      (1+0j)      1  True
#3      1      1.0      (1+0j)      1  True
#4      1      1.0      (1+0j)      1  True

df.memory_usage(index=False)
#int64         40000
#float64       40000
#complex128    80000
#object        40000
#bool           5000
```

Concerning the `boolean`, it is rather easy. It has 2 possible state and will therefore hold either 0 (false) or 1 (true). It's going to be stored in a single byte (8 bits).

Now, for the other columns : `int64` and `float64` means that you have an **integer** containing 64bits, so 8 bytes. That's 8 times bigger than the previous `boolean` value ! And it verifies quite simply if we look at above `df.memory_usage()`, if we multiply the memuse of the `bool` column (5000) by 8 (bytes), it does answer to `40000`.

The same logic applies for the `complex128`. 128 bits goes to 16 bytes, which multiplied by the 5000 columns gives us 80000. The number returned by memuse.

---

#### Where it gets tricky.

```
df['object'].memory_usage(index=False)
#40000
df['object'].memory_usage(index=False, deep=True)
#160000L
```

An `object` in pandas, is technically an array of things. Pandas is basically an abstraction of `numpy` for holding objects of any type, and that's why it is so widely used. Numpy can only store numerical data, but pandas can store nearly **any** type, since it includes `iteration` combined with `strings`.

When you are loading your DataFrame, you only need the **first reference** to your data to work with it. And when you don't activate the `deep=True` option, it will not search for the usage of the WHOLE DataFrame, but what's it is actually using : meaning the first pointer/reference to your data *(because, **VERY simply put**, the first reference leads to the data it points to AND, using what we know of this reference, we know where the next reference will be)*, which is a 64bits data, so 8 bytes data, so `40000` bytes for the 5000 rows without the `deep=True` option.

Comment: Thank you. Could you elaborate on this part about the first reference to the data? Does this mean that all of my columns being objects, calling `memory_usage(deep=False)` returns only the size of the pointers to the "beginning" of my columns? But how can this sum to more than one GB then? Also, does this mean that the rest of the data is "not really" in memory?

Comment: Hey, it's me again :) Could you confirm this is what you meant: the 'object' column takes 40kB according to deep=False because 5k rows times the size of integer 1 (=8 bytes), which is the reference needed to build the object 1? Then deep=True gives 160kB because if we look at the size of the resulting object, we get 24 bytes, which if multiplied by 5k gives 120kB? Or is this nonsense ?